# Javascript, running functions or getting global variables of obfuscated code

Tags: javascript, jquery, obfuscation

I just bought this javascript obfuscation script: http://codecanyon.net/item/php-javascript-obfuscator/411175?ref=WiseLoop

Now I want to run a function in the script that is obfuscated. Ofcourse that doesn't work any more because the function names are changed. How is this achieved?

Thanks.

Comment: Doesn't the project have documentation to tell you how to use it?

Comment: As you bought it, you should ask the seller? What does the manual say? Does it only obfusciate whole scripts (including globals) so you have to run it over your invocation code, too?

Comment: Either A. Obfuscate it together; or B. (better) Don't obfuscate it. Security through obscurity is a really poor concept and surely won't slow down any potential attacker.

Comment: I bought this lock to my door and now I can't get into my house!

Comment: This software is of course not open-source (there are some open source js obfuscators but they're mostly not used) so we can't help you.